# Colors in fzf.vim

Tags: vim, vim-fzf

How can I keep the same colours for fzf.vimp pop-up window as in terminal? The latest update changes it to current Vim theme  using g:fzf_colors. I've tried setting it to "", also tried to change colour specs to Ignore but that didn't work. I have semi-transparent background in terminal and that's what used to show in the FZF window in Vim, although the Vim background was grey (Zenburn).

Vim 8.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:h g:fzf_colors` indicates

```
    " Customize fzf colors to match your color scheme                                          
    " - fzf#wrap translates this to a set of `--color` options                                 
    let g:fzf_colors =                                                                         
    \ { 'fg':      ['fg', 'Normal'],                                                           
      \ 'bg':      ['bg', 'Normal'],                                                           
      \ 'hl':      ['fg', 'Comment'],                                                          
      \ 'fg+':     ['fg', 'CursorLine', 'CursorColumn', 'Normal'],                             
      \ 'bg+':     ['bg', 'CursorLine', 'CursorColumn'],                                       
      \ 'hl+':     ['fg', 'Statement'],                                                        
      \ 'info':    ['fg', 'PreProc'],                                                          
      \ 'border':  ['fg', 'Ignore'],                                                           
      \ 'prompt':  ['fg', 'Conditional'],                                                      
      \ 'pointer': ['fg', 'Exception'],                                                        
      \ 'marker':  ['fg', 'Keyword'],                                                          
      \ 'spinner': ['fg', 'Label'],                                                            
      \ 'header':  ['fg', 'Comment'] }
```

i put this in my `~/.vim/plugin/fzf-options` (but you could put it directly in your `.vim/vimrc` file as well).

And it made it match the theme colors.